# What is the probability that exactly 3 repairers are called out of 4 repairers?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A town contains 4 people who repair televisions. If
4 sets break down, what is the probability that exactly 3
of the repairers are called?

My approach:

2 TVs have to be repaired by the same repairer and the other 2 TVs by one repairer each:

2 choose 1 repairer: ${4 \choose 2}{3 \choose 1}$ because 2 of the TVs are chosen among all 4 TVs and then 1 repairer is chosen among 3 repairers.

1 choose 1 repairer: ${3 \choose 1}{2 \choose 1}$ because we chose 1 tv among the remaining 3 TV's and then 1 repairer among the remaining 2 repairers.

1 choose 1 repairer: ${2 \choose 1}{1 \choose 1}$ same thinking here.

Cardinality(S) = $4^4$ so we have $\frac{{4 \choose 2}{3 \choose 1}{3 \choose 1}{2 \choose 1}{2 \choose 1}{1 \choose 1}}{4^4}$

Is that correct?

Comment: You can produce the expression $\binom{n}{k}$ by typing `$\binom{n}{k}$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is incorrect.  In your attempt, you did not first select which three of the four repairers were called.  You also seem to have lost track of how many television sets had not been assigned.

There are $4$ ways to select the repairer who repairs two sets, $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to select the two sets that person repairs, $\binom{3}{2}$ ways to select two of the other repairers to repair one set each, and $2!$ ways to assign those two repairers to fix those sets.  Hence, the number of favorable cases is
$$\binom{4}{1}\binom{4}{2}\binom{3}{2}2!$$
Thus, the probability that exactly three of the four repairers are called to fix the four broken sets is
$$\frac{\dbinom{4}{1}\dbinom{4}{2}\dbinom{3}{2}2!}{4^4}$$

Comment: Thank you. Why would $ {4 \choose 1} * {4 \choose 2} * {3 \choose 1} * {2 \choose 1}*2! $ not be correct (for the numerator)? (Choosing the last 2 repairers separately)

Comment: The terms $\binom{4}{1}\binom{4}{2}$ select the repairer who repairs two sets and selects the two sets that repairer fixes.  Say the remaining two broken sets belong to Ada and Brian.  There are three ways to select which of the remaining repairers will fix Ada's set and two ways to select which of the remaining repairers will fix Brian's set.  Hence, the number of favorable cases can be expressed as $\binom{4}{1}\binom{4}{2}\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{1}$.  Multiplying that result by $2!$ orders the two repairers who fix one set each a second time, doubling the actual count.